# Responsive Image Slider not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The Navigation Bar is working but the carousel is not working.
Tried it in many ways but image slider is not visible. Bootstrap is also linked.
 Read the documentation of Bootstrap Carousel but it didnt helped.
Help me out.

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Suburban Coderspoint</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
<div class="container fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/SC_167_54.png"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target="#navbarResponsive">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" ></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tutorials</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Team</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Connect</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<!--- Image Slider -->
<div id="slides" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
        <li data target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2" ></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/background.png">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/background2.png">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/background3.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,700');

/*---Media Queries --*/
@media (max-width: 992px) {}
@media (max-width: 768px) {}
@media (max-width: 576px) {}

/*---Firefox Bug Fix --*/
.carousel-item {
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}

/*--- Fixed Background Image --*/
figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 0!important;
}
.fixed-wrap {
  clip: rect(0, auto, auto, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#fixed {
  background-image: url('img/mac.png');
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
          transform: translateZ(0);
  will-change: transform;
}

/*--- Bootstrap Padding Fix --*/
[class*="col-"] {
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

[The Output Screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRqnz.png)
You can see there is no image slider anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set one `.carousel-item` to active (by adding `.active` class). 
You have added it to the carousel indicators, but not the actual slides.

Also be sure you are including the required Bootstrap JavaScript dependencies.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="img/background.png">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="img/background2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="img/background3.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ya i have made the first one active..class= "active"

Comment: Your posted code does not reflect that, you added to indicators.

Comment: then where should i add..please guide me or change that part and post the code in answer

Comment: @ArunavaSaha I've updated the block needing the change above - adding 'active' to the first item

Comment: ya seen it ...it got visible but slider is not working and it isn't responsive and it destroyed the whole orientation of the page including the navbar

Comment: You have it inside the navbar. If this is not what you were intending, you would need to move it below.

Comment: ya but one last help..the slider is leaving some part of the screen on the right side...its not displaying on the whole division.  Hope you can help.

Comment: make sure your images are large enough, but also verify you are using `.container`, `.row` and `.col` classes correctly. you may need to add `.no-gutters` to your `.row` to extend to the full width - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/